# Constraint on Primal and Dual variables

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, duality-theorems

I have an LP problem, let $x$ denote the decision variables of the Primal and $y$ denote the decision variables of the Dual.

Then, I have an additional constraint: $g(x,y) \leq 0$

Does anyone have an idea how to approach this kind of problem?

Thanks very much!

Comment: How does this problem emerge? Maybe the construction might yield some insight to the problem, but, as it stands, the dual variables depend on how the problem is set up, too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Guillermo. I'll try to explain better: a set of constraints in the primal problem has corresponding dual variables, which itself appear in other constraints in the primal problem - so the primal and dual are weirdly nested. I've never seen it before - if you have any tips on how to untangle this that'd be helpful. Also could this kind of problem be specified in a standard LP solver?

Comment: Right, is there any way that you can give an example of what this problem looks like?/how this problem emerges? It's not clear to me how you can place constraints on both the primal and dual variables and still have zero duality gap on the LP; which makes me think this might be an NP-hard problem.